# Can I use Powershell command window to interact with a Powershell hosting app?

Tags: powershell, embed, powershell-hosting

I'm working on an application to have Powershell embedded in it. I'm wondering if there is a way I can launch a separate Powershell command window, and interact with my application through this Powershell window? Can anyone point out some reference? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I figure out what I can do in this case, is to create a PowerShell provider in my application. With this provider, user will be able to interact with the application through PowerShell running outside of the application.

Comment: This was a real answer until you asked "Any Comments?"  It is pointless to ask questions in answers; nobody will see them.  If you have a real question, you can ask it in the usual way.

Comment: Yes. I just implemented what I mentioned above. That works. In a separate PowerShell console, I can import module of my own assembly, and start to create objects and methods provided by my application.